# CHKCONFIG NOT working on UBUNTU 12.04.4

Tags: command-line, apt, ssh

I am trying to install `chkconfig` in Ubuntu 12.04.4 but it is not installing.
I have tried most of the solutions available like

```
apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
update-rc.d
```

All of the above is giving the below error

> "Package is not available, but is referred to by another package... E:
>   Package 'chkconfig' has no installation candidate".

I am clueless now what to do as I have to install and enable the ssh ....

any other solution to enable and start the SSH...???

Comment: Oh yes that was the problem as soon as enabled Software sources everything worked fine......

Comment: I am writing it as an answer, mark it accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/sysv-rc-conf that package is in the universe repository.
Make sure you have a line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` that looks like this:

```
deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
```

Then run `apt-get update` to update your package list.
The package should then be installable.

Answer (score 0):

Packages you are trying to install (i.e `chkconfig` and `sysv-rc-conf` ) are in Universe Repository ( [chkconfig](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/chkconfig), [sysv-rc-conf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/sysv-rc-conf) ).

So you have to enable the Universe Repository so that you install software from it.

To enable it

- Open ***Software Sources***
- Under ***Ubunut software*** tab ,check the option "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe).

Now Run `sudo apt-get update`.